# How to implement a dropdown in a TableView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to implement a dropdown in a `UITableView` by clicking a button within the cell and insert a subview(image for background) like below to show the expansion. I have seen `tableView` expansions from within sections, which is what I don't want. Basically, I need to implement only one section. Any idea how this could be done?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSixW.png]

[image: normal cell]

[image: expanded cell]

Comment: You can use picker instead of dropdown

Comment: Try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34586224/3908884

Answer (score 1):

First of all you didn't explained it properly what you want? Based on your topic i got you want drop down menu.But,i have to inform you there is no such thing within the iOS SDK.

So,you have to apply some tricks to get it done.
suppose you can hide a table which contains the drop down list and show it while detecting user touch.There are some Links who are really done it nicely.Just check it out.

http://code4app.net/ios/Drop-Down-Menu/503c3a446803fabd1c000002

https://github.com/romaonthego/REMenu

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/nidropdown

Hope these links will help you out and sorry for sharing links but this question needs it.
I have done something similar to this if you want any further help,feel free to ping me.

Thanks

Comment: I added two more images to explain the requirement.

Comment: @Sushrut I have seen the images and its easy to do it..please read these link carefully you will get it..If i will get time then i will try to write some code snippets for you..